# Why image didn't appear and display in another page of php after submitted?

Tags: php, html

I going to design 2 php page,one is personal detail form must filled by the users and another one is display all personal details where they had been done in personal detail form after submit.My problem is that the image that had submitted didn't display on the 2nd page.What wrong with my code?My code shown as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
//for preview a image 
   <script type="text/javascript">
 function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <form name="rform" method="get" action="researchers.php">  
        <h4>Researchers Profile</h4> 

         <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>
        <form id="form1" method="get" action="researchers.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="pro_image">
       <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" name="image" id="image"/>
        <br><img id="blah" src="profile pic.jpg" alt="your image" width="160px" height="120px"/><br/>
        </form>

     <input type="submit" name="savebtn" value="Save"/>
     </form>
```

The researchers.php page

```
<?php

 $name=$_FILES['image']['name']; 
 $tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 $new=time().$name;
 $new="upload/".$new;
 move_uploaded_file($tmp,$new);
 if($_FILES['image']['error']==0)
  {

 ?>
 <br /><img src="<?php echo $new;?>" width="100" height="100"/>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: you have `<form ..` twice

Comment: ok,thank for your remind...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `<form>` method to `post` as from the php manual for `$_FILES` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

> Description
>
> An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

You will need to also add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype

```
<form name="rform" method="post" action="researchers.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

see also http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Have you looked at your output html img source code `<img src="..." />` to make sure that it is a valid link? Have you made sure that the file is in the `upload` directory?

Comment: Actually after user choose their file based on the `file` from the input type,then their opted file will store in default directory for retrieve the image file and display on `researchers.php` page.I don't really understand what you mean in valid link of <img src='..'>?And should we have to create directory for store image/file manually?